# Cannot find imageBimap method of CardType

Tags: android, credit-card

I am using the card.io library and I used the CardType library. I would like to use the method `imageBitmap` present in the reference : http://card-io.github.io/card.io-Android-SDK/ but eclipse doesn't seem to recognize it :

```
public void createLogoInCard(Drawable drawable, CardType cardType, Context context) {
    Bitmap cardTypeLogo = cardType.imageBitmap(context);
}
```

The line in the method is not correct and eclipse does not give it to me among the other methods of CardType...

Is there a reason for that ?

Comment: please post some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like jar file for `v.3.1.4` is broken, so I suggest you to download `v.3.1.3` from here https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/archive/3.1.3.zip This version works fine for me:

```
CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
CardType cardType = creditCard.getCardType();
cardType.imageBitmap(this);
```

By `this` I've used `Activity` class